# Is this the correct way to write a CFT for lambda to be triggered by SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

Hello I recently made a CFT for my lambda and sqs (both on the same account/region) but I noticed that when I go to the aws console, it shows the SQS resource both on the "input side" and the "output side" of my lambda. Is this intentional? or did I just do my CFTs incorrectly. Below is the relevant JSON code.

```
 "MyLambdaFunctionRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "root",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                    "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                    "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
                    ],
                  "Resource": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:test-${Environment}-my-queue"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

```
    "OutputRouterEventSource": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping",
      "Properties": {
        "BatchSize": 10,
        "Enabled" : true,
        "EventSourceArn": {
          "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:test-${Environment}-my-queue"
        },
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "MyLambdaFunction",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

```
    "OutputRouterLambdaInvokePermission": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
    "Properties": {
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Principal": "sns.amazonaws.com",
      "SourceArn": {
        "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:test-${Environment}-my-queue"
      },
      "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::Sub": "test-${Environment}-my-lambda"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to have SQS on both side in this case: SQS triggers your Lambda function (left side) and your Lambda function's role must have the permission to receive and delete messages from the queue (right side).

(I think your are mixing services in your `OutputRouterLambdaInvokePermission` resource where the principal is SNS and the source references the arn of a SQS queue, you can drop this resource as it is not needed for SQS triggers)